# Permission Denied when using AMQP 0-9-1 with WSO2 MB

Tags: wso2, amqp

When trying to communicate with WSO2 MB using AMQP 0-9-1 I receive a 'permission denied' AMQSecurityException from the Andes core of WSO2 MB.  This occurs because I am trying to bind a queue to a topic using a routing key.  Can anyone provide guidance on how to use an AMQP 0-9-1 library with WSO2 MB?

Specifically my code is attempting to publish to the exchange 'texch' with routing key 'rkey' and consume messages via a runtime created queue bound to 'texch' with routing key 'rkey'.

The output from WSO2 MB is:

```
[2013-04-02 14:27:34,012]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Closing channel due to: org.wso2.andes.AMQSecurityException: Permission denied: binding rkey [error code 403: access refused]
[2013-04-02 14:27:34,015]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Channel[1] awaiting closure - processing close-ok
[2013-04-02 14:27:34,015]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.handler.ChannelCloseOkHandler} -  Received channel-close-ok for channel-id 1
[2013-04-02 14:27:36,424]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.store.CassandraMessageStore} -  Removed Global Queue Assigned for Topic Subscription: tmp_1792d33b-7975-44db-b68f-dc54ce9a0852
```

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 Message Broker the exchanges will not be created dynamically for any name given.Therefore if it for topics we need to use "amq.topic", the pre-defined default topic exchange name of WSO2 MB as the exchange name, and if it is for Queues default exchange needs to be 'amq.direct' to avoid this permission issue.

In addition if there is new topic/direct exchange needs to be created ( as 'texch' in your case), it needs to be pre-declared in qpid-virtualhosts.xml file and then you can bind the queue/topic into the new exchange. Refer [this](http://isharapremadasa.blogspot.com/2013/08/using-wso2-message-broker-with-rabbitmq.html) blog post for further guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

We have to configured quid-virtualhost.xml file as below to create Q at server start up.

```
            <!-- Here you can add remove exchange to this virtualhost-->
            <exchange>
                <type>direct</type>
                <name>carbon.direct</name>
                <durable>true</durable>
            </exchange>
            <exchange>
                <type>topic</type>
                <name>carbon.topic</name>
            </exchange>
        </exchanges>

        <queues>
            <queue>
                <name>TEST</name>
                <TEST>
                    <exchange>carbon.direct</exchange>
                    <durable>true</durable>
                </TEST>
            </queue>
```

I have used the "amqp-ts" to send and receive messages from javascripts.

```
 var amqp = require("amqp-ts");

var connection = new amqp.Connection("amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672");
//var exchange = connection.declareExchange("carbon.direct",{noCreate: true});
var queue = connection.declareQueue("TEST",{noCreate: true});
//queue.bind(exchange);
queue.activateConsumer((message) => {
    console.log("Message received: " + message.getContent());
});

// it is possible that the following message is not received because
// it can be sent before the queue, binding or consumer exist
var msg = new amqp.Message("Test");
queue.send(msg);

connection.completeConfiguration().then(() => {
    // the following message will be received because
    // everything you defined earlier for this connection now exists
    var msg2 = new amqp.Message("Test2");
    queue.send(msg2);
});
```

for more reference https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node